# Yii2: Need to click submit button twice, name and id is not "submit"

Tags: php, html, forms, yii2

Problem: I have three forms in one page, that all have the same bug: I need to click the submit button twice in order to submit the form.

I have discovered that this is a common bug and usually triggered by naming the button "submit", however this is not the case.

Here's my code:

(First form: Change Password)

```
<div id="change-password-form">
    <?php $changePasswordForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'          => 'change-password-form',
        "options"     => ["class" => "animated-label"],
        "fieldConfig" => ["template" => "{input}\n{label}\n{hint}\n{error}"],
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changePasswordForm->field($changePassword, 'newPassword')->passwordInput() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changePasswordForm->field($changePassword, 'repeatNewPassword')->passwordInput() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changePasswordForm->field($changePassword, 'oldPassword')->passwordInput() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= Html::submitButton(
                'Change Password',
                [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    "style" => "width: 100%",
                    'name'  => 'submit-change-password',
                    'id'    => 'submit-change-password',
                ]
            ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

(Second form: Change Email)

```
<div id="change-email-form">
    <?php $changeEmailForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'          => 'change-email-form',
        "options"     => ["class" => "animated-label"],
        "fieldConfig" => ["template" => "{input}\n{label}\n{hint}\n{error}"],
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changeEmailForm->field($changeEmail, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changeEmailForm->field($changeEmail, 'email')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
            <?= Html::submitButton(
                'Change Email',
                [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    "style" => "width: 100%",
                    'name'  => 'submit-change-email',
                    'id'    => 'submit-change-email',
                ]
            ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

(Third form: Change Username)

```
<div id="change-username-form">
    <?php $changeUsernameForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'          => 'change-username-form',
        "options"     => ["class" => "animated-label"],
        "fieldConfig" => ["template" => "{input}\n{label}\n{hint}\n{error}"],
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changeUsernameForm->field($changeUsername, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $changeUsernameForm->field($changeUsername, 'username')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
            <?= Html::submitButton(
                'Change Username',
                [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    "style" => "width: 100%",
                    'name'  => 'submit-change-username',
                    'id'    => 'submit-change-username',
                ]
            ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

As you can see, the submit buttons have both unique IDs and names, they are correctly resolved to the desired HTML code.

E.g. the submit button of "change password" looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit-change-password" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit-change-password" style="width: 100%">Change Password</button>
```

Are there any solutions or workarounds for this case? I have only found the solution about renaming the submit buttons.

Comment: I haven't noticed anything suspicious from the first look. Have you tried looking at console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: The Dev Tools console does not throw any errors, neither do the Yii2 dev tools.

Comment: I can't tell anything from here. There might be something outside of your provided code that stops from submitting the form. Maybe something from JavaScript, for example.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking for an answer to this particular situation, in my case, I solve it by removing the extra attribute on the active form begin part.
Example: Before

```
ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'registration-form'])
```

After

```
ActiveForm::begin()
```

Now I am not really sure, how this was causing the problem. I have other forms in which I have the extra attributes and it works completely fine on those forms. I check the console for errors but could not find any. My guess is on my particular form with this issue, I was using external js file required for plugin and somehow it was causing some kind of conflict with yii validation or bootstrap js files.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the same and had a button which looked like this:
`<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn-lg btn-success', name => 'submit', 'value' => 'Save']); ?>`
After deleting the name argument, it worked like it is supposed to.